# How open a GIF image in with turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, animated-gif

I tried to animate my GIF image but it does not work, this is my code :

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
screen.addshape('black.gif')
t1.shape('black.gif')
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your python code and your gif is in the same folder and then try this code:

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500) # You can change the dimensions(500, 500) to any number
t = turtle.Turlte()
screen.addshape("name_of_the_gif.gif") #don't forget they have to be in the same file
t.shape("name_of_the_gif.gif")# make the same gif as the screen.addshape
```